# What does preverification of J2ME application mean?

Tags: java, java-me

I read the following:

```
J2ME applications, unlike normal Java applications are preverified.
```

What exactly does the preverification of J2ME jar file mean? Is it something like checksum?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [here](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=201507):

> Answer  Preverification is a new phase
>   in the development and deployment
>   cycle for Java applications designed
>   to run on the J2ME CLDC.
>   Preverification performs certain
>   checks on the Java bytecodes ahead of
>   runtime. If this first verification
>   pass is ok, the preverifier annotates
>   the classfiles (using standard Java
>   bytecode "attributes", so that these
>   are still plain old Java bytecodes and
>   will be executable in VMs not aware of
>   the benefits of preverification), and
>   then saves the annotated class files
>   or passes them along to the next tool
>   in the compile chain.
>
> When the KVM attempts to run execute a
>   J2ME CLDC-based application, it checks
>   the Java class files for these
>   preverification annotations. Proper
>   annotations in the class files
>   guarantee that certain compile-time
>   checks were made, and so the KVM can
>   pass through its own verfication and
>   security checks much faster and start
>   executing the application more
>   quickly.
>
> Sun's CLDC reference implementation
>   SDK includes the 'preverify' tool. You
>   use the tool after compiling your code
>   via javac (or your favorite Java
>   compiler). More information on
>   preverify is included in the CLDC
>   specification and in the developer
>   docs included with the CLDC SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Preverification performs certain checks on the Java bytecodes ahead of runtime. If this first verification pass is ok, the preverifier annotates the classfiles (using standard Java bytecode "attributes", so that these are still plain old Java bytecodes and will be executable in VMs not aware of the benefits of preverification), and then saves the annotated class files or passes them along to the next tool in the compile chain.

Comment: You should add the reference to the site where you got this answer from, it is exactly the place where I got my answer from.